# Opening onenote password-protected files in windows 10

Tags: windows, passwords, microsoft-onenote

I have this problem: I have some OneNote password-protected files that I created with Office 2010 (and of course I know the pwd). Now I moved to a new laptop with Windows 10 and don't have the old OneNote any more. OneNote for Windows 10 does not have a "Open file" option, but if I I double-click on a regular (non pwd-protected) OneNote file it gets open without any problem. However, if I double-cick on the pwd-protected files, I can see only for a fraction of a second the screen asking for the password, but it disappears immediately and there is no way of bringing it back. Needless to say, the file is not open.
Can anybody help me on this issue? I did some search on the Internet with no luck at all, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this.  Download the free Win32 version of OneNote: http://www.onenote.com/download/win32/x86/en-US

And then load up the OneNote files and send them to the cloud, using the same account you are using with the Windows 10 version. They will then show up on Windows 10's OneNote.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Be careful linking directly to executable files - people are unlikely to trust a direct link to a download. Can you add a link to the download page so visitors can see the source of the download? In this case I think it's http://www.onenote.com/download/

Comment: Thank you Jayongg, I had indeed come to a similar solution. Only problem, I couldn't find a link to an older version of OneNote - using this laptop (windows 10) I always ended up with the same version. Eventually I got an old PC with windows XP. I was able to install OneNote, opened the files and removed the password. Thanks for the help